# How to run unit test subset in Mocha framework?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I use `mocha --recursive --timeout 15000` CLI command to run all test placed in `/test` local folder. How can I target specific folder ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to specify test directory for mocha?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10753288/how-to-specify-test-directory-for-mocha)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few options here depending on exactly what you need, imho straight execution based on path gets a bit cumbersome.

**Directory based segregation of tests**

Everything in a directory - `mocha test/<folderPath>/*.js`

Everything including sub-directories - `mocha test/<folderPath>/**/*.js`

**Pattern matching for suites ( or tests )**

Suite - `mocha --grep <suiteName>`

Pattern Match - `mocha --grep <pattern>`

**Negative Pattern matching for suites ( or tests )**

Suite - `mocha --grep <suiteName> --invert`

Pattern Match - `mocha --grep <pattern> --invert`

**Tagging**

You can also execute test based on `tags` within the it() portion of the test.

Tagging uses the --grep feature which also allows for negative tag matching.

More can be found here - https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/Tagging

Answer (score 1):

You can just run:

mocha path-to-dir/**/*.js --timeout 15000

The two ** are the same as --recursive