# mocha is not finding my path when using mocha.opts

Tags: mocha.js

I found a [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25150994/571380) on how to get mocha to recognize that my tests files are located in another path and to recursively traverse that path - create `mocha.opts` in the `./test` folder. However, I'm having some issue with the file. Here's what I have in my mocha.opts file:

```
services/endpoints
--recursive
```

The test files themselves (200Tests.js, 400Tests.js, etc) live in various paths:

```
./test/services/endpoints/
                    |---users
                    |---persons
                    |---|---findByName
                    |---|---|---200Tests.js
                    |---|---|---400Tests.js
                    |---|---findById
                    |---|---|---200Tests.js
                    |---|---|---400Tests.js
```

etc.

From my project root, I issue `mocha` from the terminal and get: `Error: cannot resolve path (or pattern) 'services/endpoints'`. Am I doing something wrong or missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `test/services/endpoints` in your `mocha.opts` file.

The directory from which Mocha interprets paths is the directory from which the `mocha` executable is launched, which is normally the top level of your project rather than the `test` subdirectory.