# How do I set the directory for the test folder in Visual Studio Code with Mocha?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, visual-studio-code, mocha.js

I've been trying to learn unit-testing with Mocha using Visual Studio Code, as per [this tutorial.](https://dev.to/wabbbit/debugging-es6-mocha-unit-tests-using-vs-code-12ki) But when I click the Play button to start Mocha Tests, I get an error about not finding the test files.

It apparently wants me to put the test files in a directory that'd kind of mess up the way I have things organized in my project.

So, is there a way for me to point it to the test folder I have set up elsewhere?

Comment: this is a similar issue, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10753288/how-to-specify-test-directory-for-mocha i hope this help. but in my opnion go to jest <3

Comment: @Tespy I have a [simple project in GitHub](https://github.com/balexandre/so59977566) for answering another question, you can actually see how mocha works there ... feel free to download all files (or clone) and run in your computer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To tell Mocha to [run the tests in another folder](https://mochajs.org/#the-test-directory) rather than run in the default `./test` folder, you could simply change the command and execute

```
mocha "./spec/**/*.js"
```

or, if your bash does not support `**` run as

```
mocha --recursive "./spec/*.js"
```

this means, that you can easily change the VSCode launch script to:

```
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Mocha Tests",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha",
    "args": [
        "./<YOUR_FOLDER_HERE>/**/*.js",
        "--ui bdd",
        "--timeout 15000",
        "--sort",
        "--colors",
        "--bail",
        "-R spec",
        "--recursive",
        "--exit",
    ],
    "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart"
}
```

*remember to change `<YOUR_FOLDER_HERE>` with the folder name where you have the tests*

if you have tests in your code but they are named, for example as `routes.spec.js` you can simply say `./**/*.spec.js` and will find every file in your project that ends with `.spec.js`

The example above would be the same as having a `mocha.opts` file as

```
# mocha options
--ui bdd
--timeout 15000
--sort
--colors
--bail
-R spec
--require test/prepare
--recursive
--exit
```

just play with the arguments until you run it as you like ...

BTW, **if you're using VSCode**, I would strongly recommend a [Mocha extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hbenl.vscode-mocha-test-adapter) (there are several) as you will not need to run the tests as a launch command and **you will have all the tests in your sidebar with the option to debug each one** and add breakpoints to your code

[image]

as well in your tests

[image]

P.S. this project [is in GitHub](https://github.com/balexandre/so59977566) so you can see how everything works, including code coverage if you into looking how that also works :)

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked great ^_^ Now I can make programming for a certain game engine way easier xD