# Mocha tests and require cache issues

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js

I'm trying to somewhat separate my tests into `unit`, `integration` and `qa_requires` folders. So I though of this structure:

```
| /app
|  | ...
| /tests
|  | unit\
|  |  | file1.js
|  |  | file2.js
|  | integration\
|  |  | file1.js
|  |  | file2.js
|  | qa_requires\
|  |  | file1.js
|  |  | file2.js
```

AFAIK, there's a caching mechanism in node to handle requires [as read here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/requiring-modules-in-node-js-everything-you-need-to-know-e7fbd119be8/) but, the files are in different folders and I can't tell what I'm doing wrong for node to avoid requiring all tests.

**Question**: Why if I test all files under /tests with a mocha call without arguments (`node_modules/.bin/mocha`) it finds `/test/unit/file1.js` and `/tests/integration/file2.js` and nothing more?

Comment: Could not get your issue? Are you saying that you want to test a particular file and running all the tests together?

Comment: I'm trying to test all files under `/tests` with a `mocha` call without arguments. It resolves `/test/unit/file1.js` and `/tests/integration/file2.js` and nothing more

Comment: You can refer here to use --recursive option after you specify folder name . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10753288/how-to-specify-test-directory-for-mocha

Answer (score 0):

Well, after many tries (and writing this post) I fixed directory structure.

```
From                   To
| /app                 | /app
|  | ...               |  | ...
| /tests               | /tests
|  | file1.js          |  | unit\
|  | file2.js          |  |  | file1.js
|  |                   |  |  | file2.js
|  | integration\      |  | integration\
|  |  | file1.js       |  |  | file1.js
|  |  | file2.js       |  |  | file2.js
|  | qa_requires\      |  | qa_requires\
|  |  | file1.js       |  |  | file1.js
|  |  | file2.js       |  |  | file2.js
```

It seems files in `tests` root were affecting `integration` and `qa_requires` includes. @Owner's recommendation to use `--recursive` is required when working deep directories.