# How specify test-files with .mocharc config file

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I currently run mocha tests with npm scripts like

```sh
mocha test/mocha.js test/crc/mocha.js test/multibyte/test.js
```

I added additional three test files and I start to wonder maybe use configuration file like `.mocharc.js`, and call simply `mocha`, but what ever I try mocha always runs all .js files in "test" folder.

- I started with [this tutorial](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/mocha-migrating-from-mocha-opts-to-mocharc-js-configuration-file) where they use `file` property, but it wont work.
- Some SO answer points me to [mocha example on github](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/master/example/config/.mocharc.js) where they use `watch-files` property but it still wont work.
- I tried use absolute path, relative path
- according to [mocha official documentation](https://mochajs.org/#-file-filedirectoryglob) I should use `file` property, but it wont work

All this is so confusing and I cant find any config file documentation, more than what file names should I use.

Does anyone knows how I can run just these three test-files with config file ?

I know I can use npm script like before, but maybe there is way ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `spec`:

**.mocharc.json**:

```json
{
    "spec": "./test/**/*.js"    
}
```

Some other examples are in here: [How to specify test directory for mocha?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10753288/how-to-specify-test-directory-for-mocha)